# Criteria query for join

Tags: sql, jpa, criteria

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers
ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID;
```

How can we write above SQL query in Criteria query?

Comment: By [Using the Criteria API to Create Queries](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjitv.html)

Answer (score 0):

For information and examples on the criteria API see,

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Criteria